# Explanation Asked About a Range function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, range, array.prototype.map

Here goes the code:

```
const range = (start, stop) =>
 new Array(stop - start).fill(0).map((v, i) => start + i);
```

**What purpose does stop - start serve? (I guess the length of array but I am not sure. In fact, I changed it to be an addition, and it affect nothing at all.)**

What does the parameters of the .map((v,i)) do?

**What is parameter "i", and why did we pass "v" if we werent going to use it in the first place?**

I know that .fill() is for filling the undefined indexes of array but again an explanation about that would be appreciated as well.

***This function gets the numbers between 2 given arguments.***

Example is taken from a book, I didnt write it. Book is about FP.

Comment: Yes, it's the length, and of course it makes a difference to use addition (unless `start = 0`)

Comment: "*What is parameter `i`*" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map. "*why did we pass "v" if we werent going to use it in the first place?*" - you're not passing it, you're accepting it, and it's there only so that `i` is the second parameter.

Comment: @Bergi yup couldnt see that in the first glance. thanks thou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've understood most of what this function does pretty well. I'll break it up first and then address the 3 individual questions.

### What range does:

1. Determine how many numbers to return: `(stop - start)`
2. Create an array of that length: `new Array(stop - start)`
3. Fill the array with a placeholder value `0`: `.fill(0)`
4. Loop over the array to return a new array of the desired values: `.map(...)`

### Your questions

> What purpose does stop - start serve? (I guess the length of array but I am not sure. In fact, I changed it to be an addition, and it affect nothing at all.)

Your guess is right, but the way you checked your guess was probably wrong. *The only case in which you can replace subtraction with addition here is if **start equals `0`***.

Some examples:

- `range(0, 2)` -> `[0, 1]` -> length: 2 - 0 = 2
- `range(2, 5)` -> `[2, 3, 4]` -> length: 5 - 2 = 3

---

> What does the parameters of the `.map((v,i))` do?
> What is parameter "i", and why did we pass "v" if we weren't going to use it in the first place?

The [`map` method on an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) passes three arguments to the function you pass it:

1. An element of the array
2. The index of that value
3. The whole array

Most of the times, you only need the first element. For example:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(v => v * v) // [2, 4, 9]
```

But in this case, you are actually interested in the *index*, since that's what you can use to create a range that increments every value by 1.

```
[0, 0, 0].map((v, i) => i) // [0, 1, 2]
```

Even though the `v` is not used, you have to use a placeholder to get to use the second argument.

---

> I know that .fill() is for filling the undefined indexes of array but again an explanation about that would be appreciated as well.

When you create an array using the `Array` constructor with a given length, it'll return an array that has "holes" in it. `map` will skip those holes.

To use `map`, you first have to fill in the holes.

### Other examples:

Here are 2 alternative `range` functions that might help illustrate some of the points I made.

```js
const range1 = (start, stop) =>
 new Array(stop - start)
  // Fill with the lower value of the range
  .fill(start)
  // and increment by the index of every element
  .map((x, i) => x + i);
  
  
const range2 = (start, stop) => Array
   // Use Array.from
  .from(
    // Your array with "holes" can go here
    Array(stop - start),
    // You can now skip the `fill` part
    (_, i) => start + i
  );
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. this made it way too clear. i am trying to get to the fundamentals of the language and to the functional programming. its been just a month. i think my struggle is with the optional arguments :) . thanks again for your effort.